# Elixir config providers

Tags: elixir

My task is to read the JSON file on the Application run and store it in the config. I have gone through https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Config.Provider.html

Now my config provider code is

```
defmodule JSONConfigProvider do
  @behaviour Config.Provider

  # Let's pass the path to the JSON file as config
  def init(path) when is_binary(path), do: path

  def load(config, path) do
    # We need to start any app we may depend on.
    {:ok, _} = Application.ensure_all_started(:jason)

    json = path |> File.read!() |> Jason.decode!()

    json
  end
end
```

When I try to run this through iex everything looks fine

```
JSONConfigProvider.load([existing: :config, app: [:appname]],"file_path")
```

and the next step is **Then when specifying your release, you can specify the provider in the release configuration**

I don't have the mix release. Is there any way to store this in the config(dev.ex)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My task is to read the JSON file on the `Application` run and store it in the config.

There is a confusion between *application config*, and *configuration files* where this config is [usually] loaded from.

`ConfigProvider` is used to load configuration from `.json` file into *application config*. By default, the application would load `.exs` configs only, so what you actually need would be to instruct your application to use your new provider to load the configuration from `.json`.

It does not matter, whether we are talking about releases, or not. Without syntactic sugar, one might load JSON from the file *and* alter the application config on the fly with [`Application.put_all_env/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#put_all_env/2) or [`Application.put_env/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html?#put_env/4) for fine tuning.

Releases are different in many ways (it’s out of the scope of this question,) that’s why the documentation suggests altering the `releases` section of `project` file. To load it for development, you just do:

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Application do
  @moduledoc false
  use Application

  @spec start(Application.app(), Application.restart_type()) ::
        Supervisor.on_start()
  def start(_type, _args) do
    config =
      JSONConfigProvider.load(
        [existing: :config, app: [:my_app]], "file_path")
    Application.put_all_env({:my_app, config}, persistent: true)

    ...
```

Comment: I used this in dev.exs ```config :app_name,
    atom_codes: "file_path" |> File.read!()``` and this is also working fine !

Comment: Of course, it did, `config.exs` is still plain old good [tag:elixir] code.

Comment: I landed here in a previous search for something similar: implementing a service locator or a service container in Elixir.  It leverages the same `Application.get_env` and `Application.put_env` See https://elixirforum.com/t/elixir-service-locator-service-container-mocking-3rd-party-apis-and-more/30872

Comment: The code you show above can be put in `config/runtime.exs`, guarded with an if-test depending on the environment. Thanks for this.